# Web Scraping : Get graph Coordinates from Webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I wanted some help with web scraping. I want to retrieve players ranking which are plotted on the graph in this [link](http://www.icc-cricket.com/player-rankings/profile/sachin-tendulkar)

Visit the link. Click on Rating, and then hover over the points in the plot. Its `y-coordinate` will be displayed along with other details. 
I want to extract all those details.

Any help highly appreciated.

I am attaching the screenshot also.
[image]

Comment: Where's your code with your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Each `circle` element has a `cy` attribute that we can find with the following:

```
var circ = document.querySelector('circle')
console.log(circ.getAttribute('cy') // cy= 123.586....
```

This will give you the y coordinate for the first `circle` element. You can use this idea to get all of them and find out the actual value.

Comment: `cy` values in the `circ` element is not exactly what is plotted. Can u pls check ?

Comment: `cy` gives you the point on the graph from the top that the circle element is drawn. You can use that information and figure out what it correlates to on the Y axis graph.